# How to delete lines in a file that start with # or an blank line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a hundreds of files like so

```
#foo
Keep
#Bar

These
#Foo
#Bar
Lines

Only
```

I need it to end up like this

```
Keep
These
Lines
Only
```

I'm using this regex but it doesn't remove the empty lines

```
^[#\r\n].*
```

Also i'm not sure what to replace with so that the line is completely removed

Comment: Now that you provided a sample file I see that you used unix line breaks, so you need to appreciate the hint regarding that in my answer. It really applies to all answers which include \r\n

Comment: I'm trying ^([#]+.*|)\n but it says no hits found. I have the regular expression radio button selected

Comment: What is your version of Notepad++? Older version may not support some regex features.

Comment: 5.9.2 is the version

Comment: Update to the latest version (6.9, as mentioned in the answer) and try this: ^([#]+.*|)\n It most definitely works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex with Notepad++ and leave the replace field empty:

```
^([#]+.*|)\r\n
```

Note that I assumed windows linebreaks (\r\n). If unix line breaks just use \n instead

Comment: @totalitarian Have you checked the unix line break bit? It certainly works in Notepad++ 6.7

Comment: Works now i've upgraded notepad++ to the latest version. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^([#].*$|[\r\n]){1}
```

use grouping operator to match for line with # and empty lines with \r\n directly

Comment: Why `{1}`? It is always redundant.

Comment: @gyro That's like saying you have two similar roads that you can take to get to somewhere with only the length that differs, and you always prefer the longer one because you get to destination...

Comment: @Jerry that should exactly be the answer right. if you have a match, it does shortcircuit evaluation and otherwise tries to match second..isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

At the replace box, paste this at the "Find" field:

```
^(#+[A-Za-z]*|\r\n)
```

And at the Replace field don't type anything. Click on Replace all.
[]'s

Comment: Just tested here on Windows 8 and Notepad++ v6.6.8

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex

```
^(#.*?\n|\n)
```

and replace with empty string.

### [**DEMO**](http://regexr.com/3a4pj)